# Total kinetic energy of a cluster of galaxies

Tags: astrophysics

On slide 10 of these [lecture slides](https://www.sheffield.ac.uk/polopoly_fs/1.514231!/file/PHY3262015Topic3Notes.pdf), the author explains how to calculate the total kinetic energy of a cluster of galaxies.
\begin{equation}
\left< T \right> = \frac{1}{2}\left<\sum _{i} M_{i}{v}_{i}^{2}\right>
                 = \frac{1}{2}\sum _{i} M_{i}\left<{v}_{i}^{2}\right>
                 = \frac{1}{2}M_{tot}\left<\left<{v}^{2}\right>\right>
\end{equation}

where $i$ runs over the galaxies in the cluster, and $M_{tot}$ is the total mass of the cluster. The single bracket denotes 'averaged over time', while the double bracket means 'averaged over time and then averaged over galaxies.'

But I don't understand how the last equality is derived. It looks like the author assumes $\left<{v_{i}}^{2}\right> = \left<\left<{v}^{2}\right>\right>$. Is this valid?

I checked the last equality using the following Python program

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> v2 = np.random.normal(100, 5, size=100000)
>>> M = np.random.normal(1000,10,size=100000)
>>> (M*v2).sum()
10003126609.068747
>>> M.sum() * v2.mean()
10003136213.323893
```

So, the equality should be only an approximation. Am I missing something?